# Why does lm keep the whole environment when called within a function

Tags: r

If you call `lm` or `glm` inside a function it returns the whole environment.

Example:

```
fit_lm = function(dt){
  # Do some heavy data processing
  tmp = data.frame(x = rnorm(10000000))
  # fit and return model
  return(lm(y~x, data = dt))
}

dt = data.frame(x = runif(100))
dt$y = 4 * dt$x + rnorm(100, sd = 0.5)
fit = fit_lm(dt)
```

If I look at the environment `attr(fit$terms, ".Environment")` it will contain the data used for model fitting `dt`, but also contain the data frame `tmp` even if was not used by `lm`.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: This also occurs if you call `lm()` *not* inside a function... but, it seems to me the consequences are greater when called inside a function I suppose (things not being garbage collected that you assumed would be)

Comment: The reason is that you can pass to an `lm` formula not only variables within the data.frame passed to the `data` parameter but anything that is on the search path. In order to access these variables later on, the environment is needed. However, trying to understand `lm` and the evaluation within related functions hurts my brain. So, don't quote me on this.

Comment: Thank you! @Roland, what do you mean by "anything that is on the search path"? Is this related to `...` or something else?

Comment: You can do `y <- 1:3; lm(y ~ x, data = data.frame(x = (1:3)^2))`. Functions that work with `lm` objects might need `y` later on. (You can also include functions in the formula, these might be needed later too.)

Comment: @duckmayr, yes, that is true, but if you look at the object size when called in the global environment it has size 0 (same as `pryr::object_size(environment())`). Not sure why.

Comment: @Roland, good point. I have to say it is not always easy to understand how these functions really work.

Comment: @J.C.Wahl That's because it doesn't need to allocate new memory for those objects. That's why I mean that it's a general feature of `lm()`, but doesn't really cause issues when `lm()` is called from the global environment, while calling it from a function causes allocated memory in the function to not be released as you'd think

Comment: Nice related article: [Trimming the Fat from glm() Models in R](https://win-vector.com/2014/05/30/trimming-the-fat-from-glm-models-in-r/), with some discussion in comments (e.g. Bill Venables: "_This begs the question of why the model object is so ‘obese’ in the first place_")

Comment: @Henrik That's a great resource! That article should be pretty helpful for you OP

Comment: That's a great article @Henrik. Thanks! With `lm` they "store" (pointers?) the environment in three different places: `attr(mod$terms, ".Environment")`, `attr(mod$model, ".Environment") ` and `attr(attr(mod$model, "terms"), ".Environment")`  I guess they are all pointing to the same thing in memory, so all of them have to be removed to let R free up the memory.

Comment: @Henrik I find this post informative but strange: If I wanted to store only the information necessary for prediction, I'd store the coefficients and the link function and the information about contrasts (this assumes you don't have a model like `y ~ I(foo(x))` where you would also need to store `foo`). That's it. I would not approach this by stripping down the model object, in particular an object as complex as this one. The post reads a bit like complaining about features that allow convenience (for many different purposes) while still wanting that convenience.

Comment: @J.C.Wahl Out of curiosity I was digging around a little and found this on R-devel: [Model object, when generated in a function, saves entire environment when saved](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2016-July/072924.html). No, it doesn't answer your "why" question (maybe that was answered in _Trimming the fat_?), but the set-up looks very much like yours so I thought I just as well could share it. And work-arounds are suggested.

Comment: @Henrik, very nice. I like the idea of creating an environment for evaluating `lm`, but is there a reason to why the global environment has to be the parent? (Maybe because the local seize to exist on exit?)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a good answer - ["trying to understand `lm` and the evaluation within related functions hurts my brain"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63796004/why-does-lm-keep-the-whole-environment-when-called-within-a-function?noredirect=1#comment112812320_63796004)